# Character encoding MSSQL.. ISO -> Utf-8 -> Latin-1..need reversed

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, character-encoding

We are trying to migrate database content (with a PHP script).

Content has been copied into a CMS and then written to the database. Content copied could be from any character encoding scheme (e.g. IS0-...-14) and any website.

The PHP CMS is UTF-8 so the character pasted into a textbox would be converted to UTF-8 when it was POSTed but then written to the database as Latin-1 (MSSQL db...db charset and query charset both latin-1).

We are desperately trying to think up how this could be reversed or if it is even possible (to get it so the character is fully UTF-8) in PHP.

If we can get the logic we can write an extension in C++ if PHP cant handle it (which it probably cant, mb_shite and iconv).

I keep getting lost in UTF-8 4 byte character streams (i.e. 0-127 is..ect).

Anybody got any ideas?

So far we have used PHP's ord() function to try and produce a Unicode/Acsii char ref for each char (I know ord returns ASCII but it prints character numbers over 128 which I thought was wierd if it is just meant to be ASCII, or maybe it repeats itself).

My thoughts are the latin1 will struggle to convert back to UTF-8 and will result in black diamond due to single byte char stream in Latin1 (ISO-...-1).

Comment: **Exact** duplicate of [Character encoding. ANY -> Utf-8 -> Latin-1..need reversed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479933/character-encoding-any-utf-8-latin-1-need-reversed)

Comment: @gbn have deleted that question as desperate for an answer or at least information

Comment: @CraigTaub - It's much better to clarify / update an existing question than to waste the community's time by creating duplicate questions.

Comment: Ok will do in future cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `latin1` is an 8-bit clean encoding for your database (it is in MySQL, donno about MSSQL), then you don't need to do anything to reconstruct the utf-8 string. When you pull it out of your database into PHP you will get back the same bytes you put in, i.e. UTF-8.

If `latin1` is *not* an 8-bit-clean encoding for your database then your strings are irretrievably broken. This means any characters which the database considered invalid were either dropped or replaced the moment you wrote your utf-8 string to the database. There isn't any way to recover from this.

Comment: i would have guessed MSSQL's Latin1 is an 8-bit clean encoding...So you are saying query db for a row (latin-1) then take the string in PHP (utf-8) but now the problem is the character/s could be from any character set and are we sure that the conversions are all definitely ok for any possible character (e.g. umlaut from IS-...-10)? sorry to be harsh thats just what we would need the script to be and what i am asking.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. Are you asking how to *test* that everything is ok? The only way to test is to give your system some known bytes and see that they come back out how you expect.

Comment: asking if anybody knows the possible pitfalls of converting ISO-8859-10 (for example) to Utf-8 then to Latin1 inside a database and hoping to convert that latin1 character back to UTF-8 flawlessly...for example doing it with an umlaut Ö (iso-...-10). seems to produce a null value by the time gets to the latin1 db so would be impossible i think. apologies if im wasting your time just very curious about this

Comment: This only works if your database treats "latin1" as raw bytes, as my answer explains. If it is smarter than that and will alter the bits in any way, then you simply can't store arbitrary utf-8 in this database if the database expects *real* latin1 (which probably means win1252 or iso-8859-1).

Comment: Ok, last q. so when a user pastes an umlaut from a website iso-8859-10 which is like char ref 249 or something, does it get translated to utf-8 on the page (assuming cms has header charset utf8) as soon as they paste into box OR when its posted to apache/php, think it first one?

Comment: When the browser serializes the POST request, it will serialize to utf-8. The iso-8859-10 page must declare its encoding correctly or the browser must discern it correctly. The browser/OS's internal encoding is irrelevant in this picture.

Comment: thanks. forgot about Browser using unicode....understand now...so loads char in browser in unicode (from ?), posts page to PHP (header says utf8 so serialises request data in utf-8). PHP can read the utf-8 char and has no problem from there....cheers